# rubymine scanning project directories takes too long

Tags: rubymine, rubymine-7

I am getting this issue from last few days. Rubymine keeps showing "scanning project directories" in the footer of the window for hours. Sometimes for day. This brings the issue that I am not able to click on any method and land on it. Moreover Rubymine has started to hang very frequently sometimes irrecoverably so that I have to quit and restart it. Once it even did not restart so I have to restart the computer.

I have added many projects around 10. Is it the root cause or something else. But I am not able to remove these projects so as to ease the problem.

I am using rubymine 7.0
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Same problem... I though the bottle neck was the HDD but some times they open fast in a matter of seconds. Some times it takes half an hour. Thinking of updating laptop to an SSD.

Comment: I no more open more than one project in a single window. Then only rubymine works smoothly.